# How can i convert Date to epoch (unix timestamp) in Spring boot2 with mongoDB?

Tags: spring, mongodb, jackson

I'm using Spring boot 2 with mongoDB.
Currently, With jackson serilization, Dates from API response serialized to milliseconds.

```
{

            "main_reg_dt": 1515485462433
}
```

After searching on stackoverflow, added this option to application's configuration `applcation.yaml` to this

`WRITE_DATE_TIMESTAMPS_AS_NANOSECONDS: true`

but the result is same as before.

this is how the model is implemented

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_DEFAULT)
@QueryEntity
public class Card {

    @Id
    @JsonProperty("id")
    @Field("_id")
    String id;

    @JsonProperty("main_reg_dt")
    @Field("main_reg_dt")
    Date registeredDateTime;
}
```

How can i convert Date to epoch (unix timestamp) in Spring boot2 with mongoDB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to change serialization method.

First, create custom serializer

```
public class CustomDateSerializer extends JsonSerializer {
    @Override
    public void serialize(Object o, JsonGenerator jsonGenerator, SerializerProvider serializerProvider) throws IOException {
        long formattedDate = ((Date) o).getTime() / 1000;
        jsonGenerator.writeString(String.valueOf(formattedDate));
    }
}
```

Then, add annotation for using customized serializer

```
@JsonProperty("main_reg_dt")
@Field("main_reg_dt")
@JsonSerialize(using = CustomDateSerializer.class)
Date registeredDateTime;
```

Afther this date in response will be serialized as unix timestamp